# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, debugging

Such a simple call to delegate and show textfield content fails with above message in the Subject (**EXEC_BAD...**).

Further down the debugger shows:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any help on that?

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var enteredValue: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self // <- here it fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) 
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        enteredValue.text = textField.text // <- here it fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I check with your code into my side.

I think your case is that in `enteredValue` not bind into `storyboard` that's why crash been happen.

so just map `UILabel` into `storyboard` other wise check following condition.

```
 @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        if((enteredValue) != nil){
            enteredValue.text = textField.text // <- here it fails with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
        }
    }
```